# Would you use JS template framework when using Phonegap and JQuery mobile?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using JQuery mobile to build a iOS Application using Phonegap 1.5. Since there are some components like header whiter are used on many views I wonder if I should use a template framework in JavaScript or not?

Does this slow my application down? And which one does work best with PHonegap and JQuery mobile?

Comment: your title does not match the actual question. Templating and MVC are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I use [jsrender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender) it's really easy to understand. [demos](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/index.html)